# newtxmath fails after tlmgr update

Tags: newtxmath

I updated, and now get an error with the following code and lualatex or xelatex (pdflatex is OK):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}
```

The error is this:

```
! Undefined control sequence. 
l.2619 \pdfglyphtounicode
                       {nPerp}{2AEB 2215}% .. ..
```

I assume this is a bug.

How do I report it?

Comment: I can confirm it.

Comment: newtxmath isn't intended to be used with luatex in any case, but as I posted already in chat `\usepackage{luatex85}` fixes the problem

Comment: At least you get past `\documentclass` :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the tx fonts are 8bit fonts not really ideal for luatex but you can load the luatex85 compatibility to define the pdftex compatible command names.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luatex85}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}
```

This should perhaps be reported to the newtxmath maintainer so it gives a better error or works automatically with luatex.

Comment: How does one report a bug to the newtxmath maintainer?

Comment: his email address is in the file or on the last line of http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/fonts/newtx/README

Comment: OK, it's reported, at least for newtxmath.

Comment: Michael Sharpe released v 1.601 of newtxmath, which fixes the problem. It was available today on Texlive.